# Why does sum and lambda sum differ in transform?

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

For the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key1': [1,1,1,2,3,np.nan],
    'key2': ['one','two','one', 'three', 'two','one'],
    'data1': [1,2,3,3,4,5]
})
```

The following transform using the **sum** function does not produce an error:

```
df.groupby(['key1'])['key1'].transform(sum)
```

However, this transform, also using the **sum** function, produces an error:

```
df.groupby(['key1'])['key1'].transform(lambda x : sum(x))

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 5 elements, new values have 6 elements
```

Why?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @HoriaComan The error message has been added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug, but the reason as to why the two behave differently is easily explained by the fact that pandas internally overrides the builtin `sum`, `min`, and `max` functions. When you pass any of these functions to pandas, they are internally replaced by the numpy equivalents.

Now, your grouper has NaNs, and [NaNs are automatically excluded](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#na-values-in-groupby), as the docs mention. With any of the builtin pandas agg functions, this issue appears to be handled as NaNs inserted in the output automatically, as you see with the first statement. The output is the same if you run `df.groupby(['key1'])['key1'].transform('sum')`. However, when you pass a lambda as in the second statement, for whatever reason this automatic replacement of missing outputs with NaN is not done.

A possible workaround is to group on the strings:

```
df.groupby(df.key1.astype(str))['key1'].transform(lambda x : sum(x))

0    3.0
1    3.0
2    3.0
3    2.0
4    3.0
5    NaN
Name: key1, dtype: float64
```

This way, the NaNs are not dropped, and you get rid of the length mismatch.

Comment: You wrote, "you can insert NaNs in the result yourself to get rid of the length mismatch."  It isn't clear to me what you mean there.  How would you insert NaNs in the result if the lambda is called just 5 times?

Comment: @adpatter I should say that you can get the same behaviour that pandas shows if you group on the strings, so that NaNs aren't dropped.